# using dask with a web server

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I am working on a proof of concept dask webserver based off of https://examples.dask.org/applications/async-web-server.html

In the example it looks like you are using a single global dask client to handle all requests. Is that the proper way to do it for production? Would this scale up if you have hundreds of simultaneous requests? Would there be any benefit to create a pool of clients and distribute requests across them?